# Python How to check if a target object is no longer the same instance or "valid"

Tags: python, list, object, pygame

OK in my 2d game, I have several 'cell' object instances (sprite objects) that have an empty self.target = [] attribute upon initialization.

They will then find a valid "plant" target object nearby and that will become the cells' "self.target."

The 'cell' will then navigate toward the plant to eventually collide with and eat it, and the plant is then set to ".kill()" and another is respawned at a random new coordinate. There are several plant instances (part of spr_plant_group) and several cells (belonging to spr_cell_group).

Each plant 'lives' for X game ticks (200 I think), and if not eaten by then, is .kill()-ed and a new one spawns at a random coordinate.

The problem is this: If a cell's target plant happens to despawn from age, or is eaten by something, the cell's self.target info is STILL pointing to the old "plant" object's data. This means the cell is chasing a phantom object, still apparently having a valid x and y coordinate.

Question: How do I tell the cell that it's target is dead, gone, invalid? If I can do this, I think it would fix the 'phantom' target object.

Pieces of relevant code:

```
class Agent(sprite.Sprite):

 def __init__(self, sense_range, size, food, maxspeed):

    sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.x = randint(0,450)
    self.y = randint(0,450)
    self.ang = randint(0,359)
    self.turn_rate = 2
    self.dx = 0
    self.dy = 0
    self.speed = 1
    self.maxspeed = maxspeed
    self.food = int(food)
    self.max_food = food*1.5
    self.target = []
    self.sense_range = sense_range

# Snip------This part below is supposed to find a new target, but it only
# works for the first one when the cell spawns, then I can't seem to 
# get it to become 'empty' so that the "if self.target == []" can do its 
# thing....

   def seek_food(self):

    if (self.target == []):
        #find cell a target within "sense_range" distance (say 200 pixels)
        dist = self.sense_range
        targ = []
        for t in spr_plant_group:
            t_dist = abs(self.x - t.x)
            if t_dist <= dist:
                targ = t
                dist = t_dist

        self.target = targ
        print ("Found target...",dist, self.target)

    else:
        #already have a target, so move cell toward target
        dx = self.target.x - self.x
        dy = self.target.y - self.y
        rads = atan2(dy,dx)
        rads %= 2*pi
        degs = degrees(rads)
        direction = degs - self.ang
        if direction > 0:
            self.ang = self.ang + self.turn_rate
        elif direction < 0:
            self.ang = self.ang - self.turn_rate

        # Correct for angle being out of 0-360* range
        if self.ang > 360:
            self.ang -= 360
        elif self.ang < 0:
            self.ang += 360

#---This is just a piece of the Plant class for your reference

class Plant (sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):

    sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    self.x = randint(0,450)
    self.y = randint(0,450)
    self.age = 1 + randint(0,50)
```

For reference, below. Plants age increases until 200 ticks, then they're killed, and a new one respawns...

```
def update_plants():
for shrub in spr_plant_group:
    shrub.age += 1

    # Respawn a new plant in a different place
    if shrub.age >= 200:
        shrub.kill()
        plant.append (Plant())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Actually, it's a lot simpler. [Pygame's Sprite class supports an alive method](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.alive), so just do this:

```
def seek_food(self):
    if (self.target == [] or not self.target.alive()):
        # Find a new target that isn't dead...
    else:
        # Move to the (alive) target...
```

---

You can use some variant of [the Observer design pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/observer.html). Extend your `Plant` class with an extra property which keeps track of any `Cell` instances that are targeting the plant. When a cell targets a plant, it will add itself to the plant's list. Before the plant dies, it will notify all of its cells.

**New property in the Plant class:**

```
class Plant (sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.followers = []
        # ...
```

**Cells subscribe to the plant's list of followers:**

```
def seek_food(self):
    if (self.target == []):
        # ...
        self.target = targ
        self.target.followers.append(self)
        # ...
    else:
        # ...
```

**The Plant class overrides its parent class' kill function so that it notifies its followers before dying:**

(Here, the cell class is directly modifying each plant's target, but you could encapsulate the behaviour differently if you want)

```
def kill(self):
    for follower in self.followers:
        follower.target = []
    self.followers = []

    super().kill()
```

Comment: "The Cell class overrides its parent class' kill function so that it notifies its followers before dying:"

Did you mean the >>Plant<<  class (not Cell) overrides it's kill function so it can first clear it's follower lists? That would make more sense.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and it works perfectly as I needed.

The cells reacquire a new plant target if their old one dies or gets eaten, and change their course to intercept.

Thank you! Seems like a very obvious solution with the sprite.alive() which I clearly forgot about!